# .htaccess rewrite to redirect root subdirectory to another subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to get

```
www.example.com/alpha
```

to

```
www.example.com/beta
```

I am trying this but its not working

```
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} example.com/alpha [nc]
rewriterule ^(/)?$ beta [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} example.com\alpha$
RewriteRule \beta$ - [L]
```

---

## For More Information: [Click Here](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond)

> http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond

---

Comment: This leads to 500 Internal Server Error.